# quick way to count number of rows in a csv file c++

Tags: c++

my intent is to have a progress bar update in the main gui while the worker thread is reading the csv file and signaling the main gui to update the progress.

Is there a quick way of counting the number of rows in a csv file?
the code below without processing any data takes 33 seconds to traverse the entire file.

If i include the actual processing of the data the 2nd time i read the file it takes an additional 86 seconds.

I have 10 files if i do this in series it will take me 20 minutes to load the files. I can try to read them in parallel to reduce the time, but i would like to reduce the read time for each individual file further.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
QTime myTimer;
myTimer.start();

QFile file( ui->Data->text().toStdString().c_str());
            if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
                return;

        int rows = 0;
        while (!file.atEnd())
        {
            QByteArray line = file.readLine();
            rows++;
        }

        qDebug() << "number of rows" << rows;

 /*io::CSVReader<2> in(ui->Data->text().toStdString().c_str());
    in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column,"Absolute time","Pressure");
    std::string Abst;
    double PressureData;

    in.read_row(Abst,PressureData);

    m_Pressures.reserve(1000000);

    //qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(Abst) << ts.time_since_epoch().count();

    while(in.read_row(Abst,PressureData))
    {
        time_stamp ts = convertFileNameToTimestamp(Abst);
        Pressure p(ts,PressureData);
        m_Pressures.push_back(p);
    }

    qDebug() << m_Pressures[0].GetPressure() << m_Pressures[0].GetTimeStamp().time_since_epoch().count();
    */
      int nMilliseconds = myTimer.elapsed();
        qDebug() << "Elapsed time in milliseconds" << nMilliseconds;
```

here is a row sample of the csv file.
there are 7567241 rows.

```
2019-08-31 16:28:29.283250,35.3457375033909
```

Comment: What is your Qt version?

Comment: QT 5.9.1 MSVC 2015 64 bit

Comment: Why do need the number of rows?  If it's just to measure progress, then it might be more reasonable to just use the number of characters processed, as a fraction of the file's total size?

Comment: You can use [`QFile::size()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#size) and use that for showing progress.

Comment: I'm surprised with the performance difference between release and debug. release build can read and parse the files in 8 seconds, with the debug build it takes 80 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a progress bar you could just calculate:

```
int progress_percent = processed_bytes * 100. / file_size;
```

However, knowing the number of CSV rows may allow you to preallocate column arrays to read without memory reallocations. An upper bound on the number of rows is the count of newline symbols +1 (if the last row doesn't end with a newline).